# how to open Gallery inside the Application just like Facebook messenger ????

Tags: android, facebook

I saw that in Facebook messenger Chat room , when i do the chat with any person there is option for send the picture to that person , that time when i click on icon to browse the image from gallery then all the pictures comes at bottom , them i can slide from left to right and right to left .. and when i click on picture it automatically goes to person .
        Basically i am making Android app in which i want that user upload his/her picture from gallery , i used onActivityResult , but i want just like above .
                               Thanks for your help .

Comment: you can use gallery view for this

Comment: ok thanks but can your give me some link or example

Comment: you can google it for more links and examples [link](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-gallery-view-example.html)

Comment: ok thanks i shall do ..

Comment: gallery view is deprecated !